# Novel dealing with short distance time travel and micro-black holes

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

Years ago, perhaps 20 or more, I read a novel dealing with short distance time travel and micro-black holes.  My memory seems to say it was written by James P. Hogan.  But I've searched all his novels and haven't found it.

I read this about the same time as I was reading *The Genesis Machine*.  There were two characters that were involved in testing time travel or events that took place only a few minutes apart, maybe even a few seconds.

The micro-black holes were theorized to penetrate the earth without doing much, if any, damage.

Somehow, perhaps because of relativistic effects, time was altered just enough that events that took place a few seconds earlier were made apparent in the present.

Answer (score 10):

Since you say you're thinking Hogan, I have to note that the first part of the question sounds a lot like [*Thrice Upon a Time*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1016).

The protagonist's uncle has developed an extremely limited form of time travel that allows him to send a message back in time 24 hours, no more.  The micro black holes are an unexpected product of a nearby fusion power plant, but instead of passing harmlessly through the Earth, they threaten to destroy it.

I don't recall relativity coming into it, but the increasing radiation leakage from the black holes was making it harder and harder to send the necessary information back in time to save the world.

Comment: This is the answer. As I read Jim's post I could remember reading the book myself and could remember the cover showing a man at a computer in a castle dungeon or some such. That was confirmed when I visited the link you provided. I used to own that book... I wonder where it went?

Comment: @JBH interesting that that you say " wonder where it went?" - I owned this book twice back in the 80s, lost it both times before finishing it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I once discovered I had 3 copies of the Haldemans' *There Is No Darkness*.  My collection was a bit... disorganised.

Comment: It's a time travel book...have you guys considered it might have disappeared into the past?  I mean, it knows how.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I should probably buy it once more, given the title.

Answer (score 0):

[Space Chantey](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2154101) by [R A Lafferty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._A._Lafferty) features very short distance time travel: the protagonist wins a fortune at the casino by going back 30 seconds or so every time he loses a bet.

Comment: Are there micro black holes in that novel?

Comment: @PM2Ring I didn't notice any: perhaps they were too small;-)